# Active Menu not working after trailing Slash added in .htaccss

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

I’m creating a dynamic PHP blog site, where I have active current menu by using jQuery, everything was works fine before .htaccess modification for trailing slash…

link activated

[image]

Tech is tab and contain is activated but not working Active Menu LInk

[image]

If you visit below url **Menu Active Link works fine**

```
 http://example.com/tech
```

If you visit below url than **Menu Active Link will not work**

```
http://example.com/tech/
```

For *Trailing Slash* I have use below code

**.htaccess**

```
#force trainling slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
#end of force trailing slash

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ archive.php?category=$1 [QSA,L]
```

***Menu***

```
<ul id="nav-main">
  <li><a href="http://example.com/"> Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/tech">  Technology</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/business">Business</a></li>
  <li><a href="/sports"> Sports</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/science">Science</a></li>
</ul>
```

***jQuery***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var path = window.location.href;
        $('#nav-main li a').each(function() {
            if (this.href === path) {
                $(this).addClass('active'); 
            }
        });
    });
```

***Css***

```
ul#nav-main li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #4db2ec;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul#nav-main li a.active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #4db2ec;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**N.B.:**  *The contain of the website works fine.... only ACTIVE Link not working (main problem).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this in your if :  || this.href === path + '/'

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var path = window.location.href;
    
    console.log(path);
    $('#nav-main li a').each(function() {
        if (this.href === path || this.href === path + '/') {
            $(this).addClass('active'); 
        }
    });
});
```

```css
ul#nav-main li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #4db2ec;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul#nav-main li a.active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #4db2ec;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav-main">
  <li><a href="http://example.com/"> Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/tech">  Technology</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/business">Business</a></li>
  <li><a href="/sports"> Sports</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/science">Science</a></li>
  <li><a href="/js/">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```